# Why can I not Distinct Gallery items from a SharePoint List in PowerApps

Tags: powerapps

So I consider myself pretty experienced in the PowerApps area however I have faced an issue I have never seen before and cannot find a work around.

So I have a gallery getting its data fed through a SharePoint list full of names (some repeating). I am trying to distinctly return the names and display them on a gallery only once (hence the distinct). However as soon as I wrap my filter by columns with Distinct() I get an error displaying:

[image]

How can I fix this as I have no idea why adding the Distinct is causing a problem with the default when I'm sure in the past has not been an issue. Can anyone enlighten me?

My Gallery items are:

```
Defaults('Archive')
```

And my items are:

```
Distinct(SortByColumns(Filter('ER Archive', StartsWith('Staff Name', trackSearchBar.Text)), "StaffName"), 'Staff Name')
```

And its returning information on the gallery however its giving me the error.

Answer (score 0):

**[Defaults function in Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-defaults)**

You are using two different data sources = Archive in Defaults('Archive')

and

```
ERArchive in Distinct(SortByColumns(Filter('ER Archive', StartsWith('Staff Name', trackSearchBar.Text)), "StaffName"), 'Staff Name')
```

Please follow the defaults documentation link above